# Fixed number of isolate at any point of time in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, memory-management, dart-isolates

Multiple isolates at the same time are using a lot of RAM which eventually causes the app to crash. Want a way to run only specific number of isolates at a time.

I am using a for loop and depending on number of images, the loop is executed particular number of times. In my loop I call an Isolate by using the flutterCompute() function from the [flutter_isolate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate) package. Suppose the for loop executes 50 times but I don't want 50 Isolates at the same time which will use a lot of memory and thus want a way to run only 3 isolate at any time. How can I do this?